# Enabling just one audio stream on a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, audio

I'm in the early stages of setting up a band site where there are a number of sample audio streams. Each stream is triggered or stopped by separate "Play" and "Pause" buttons. There are also a number of videos on the page which have their own controls. I used the following code for setting up the audio samples:

```
$("#play0").click(function() {

    $("#audio0").trigger('play');

});


$("#pause0").click(function() {

    $("#audio0").trigger('pause');

});
```

The "audio0" ID is for each audio stream (up to "audio9") while "play0" and "pause0" IDs (also up to "play/pause9") are for buttons. How can I make sure that at any one time, only one audio file should be playing (irrespective of whether it is audio or video). In other words, a user cannot trigger more than one audio stream to play simultaneously. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 var media = $('audio, video');

    function pauseAll() {
       media.each(function() {
          var element = $(this).get(0);
          element.pause();
       });
    }


    $("#play0").click(function(){
        pauseAll();
        $("#audio0")[0].play();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, Tambo. Your code worked like a charm. However, I had to remove the "controls" attribute in each VIDEO and define separate PLAY and PAUSE buttons. By doing that, I've lost the ability to let the user convert the videos to full-screen display, which came as part of the "controls" attribute. I tried inserting the "allowfullscreen" attribute by hand but it doesn't seem to work. So now I need the solution to be able to give the user the choice of watching the videos in full screen. Other than that, your code is a keeper!

Comment: I went back into my page and now I realize that if you right click on the video, there is an option to toggle between "Show" and "Hide" controls. If you "Show" controls, you are able to see the whole "controls" panel on the video, including the icon to go full screen. However, this is not a very elegant solution, especially since it also displays the "Play" and "Pause" buttons that come with the "controls" attribute. It could all be very confusing for the user.